# Does anyone know how or where can VADS (Verdix Ada Development Studio) can be obtained?

Tags: compiler-construction, ada

Yeah, I know is obsolete and old and everything you all might say... But I just needed... This stuff happens... xD any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rational bought Verdix in '94. IBM bought Rational in '03.

So at this point my suggestion would be to go IBM's [Ada webpage](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/developer/ada/) and follow their contact information to see if there is any way they could sell you an old VADS system.

If you totally fail at that, I believe [Ada Core](http://www.adacore.com/home/) can be contracted to port the code to their modern compiler. A thourough tested port would probably not be cheap. But then again, I remember those VADS systems going for more than $10,000...

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago I ported a large system from VADS to Rational Apex. It went fairly well, not least because Rational had made a solid effort to port the VADS-specific packages.